# Why can't EventData.GetBytes() be called before sending?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I'm working with Azure Event Hubs and initially when sending data to try and calculate batch size I had code similar to the below that would call [EventData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.aspx).[GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.getbytes.aspx)

```
EventHubClient client;//initialized before the relevant code

EventData curr = new EventData(data);
//Setting a partition key, and other operations.
long itemLength = curr.GetBytes().LongLength;
client.SendAsync(curr);
```

Unfortunately I would receive an exception in the SDK code.

> The message body cannot be read multiple times. To reuse it store the value after reading.

While removing the ultimately unnecessary call to GetBytes meant that I could send messages, the rationale for this exception to occur is rather puzzling. Calling GetBytes() twice in a row is an easy way to reproduce the same exception, but a single call will mean that the EventData cannot be sent successfully.

It seems likely that underneath a [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used and this is set to throw an exception if called more than once as [Message.GetBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195456.aspx) documents; however, there is no documentation to this effect in EventData's methods [GetBodyStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.getbodystream.aspx), [GetBody w/serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn727403.aspx), [GetBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn751690.aspx), or [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.getbytes.aspx).

I imagine this should either be documented, or corrected since currently it is an unpleasant surprise in a separate thread.

Comment: Most network/IPC related objects do not support any kind of seek/re-read/re-write, so such behavior should be somewhat expected. I have no idea whether it is documented anywhere for this particular type.

Comment: It seems like a reasonable tradeoff (if documented) for received messages, substantially less so for one that has not yet been sent.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using EventData.SerializedSizeInBytes to get the size? that is a much more accurate way to get the size for batching calculation.

Comment: As for GetBytes() behavior that you see, we will look into it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263189/how-can-the-serialized-size-of-eventdata-be-determined-for-batching was my question for that one. This question (and that one) predated SerializedSizeInBytes.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. By the way for the GetBytes() behavior it should be fixed as of Nuget build 2.6.5 https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/2.6.5

Comment: There is no SerializedSizeInBytes in Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs based EventData class. Any idea how to handle here ?