# How can the serialized size of EventData be determined for batching?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

In the documentation for the Azure [EventHubClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.aspx) there are [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatch.aspx) [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatchasync.aspx) for sending a batch of data each of them has the remark below and will throw a [MessageSizeExceededException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagesizeexceededexception.aspx) if it is ignored.

> You should ensure that the total serialized size of eventDataList is less than the size limit of one event data transmission, which is 256k by default.

A similar warning is present in the [Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn789972.aspx)

How can the serialized size of `IEnumerable<EventData> eventDataList` be determined?

The size of the bytes passed to each [EventData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.aspx) is easy enough to determine, assuming you don't [ask the EventData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241679/why-cant-eventdata-getbytes-be-called-before-sending). However, the serialized form of an EventData presumably includes the [Partition Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.partitionkey.aspx) and [user properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.properties.aspx) as used in the [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Service-Bus-Event-Hub-286fd097/sourcecode?fileId=125837&pathId=2088418849).

```
data.Properties.Add("Type","Telemetry_" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

Currently my only option looks like being conservative with batch sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**----Updating after the Nuget Update----**
Here's the EventData property - [SerializedSizeInBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata.serializedsizeinbytes.aspx) that we introduced in our recent SDK iteration - which addresses this specific problem - available in all [sdk nugets above 2.6](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) .

**---Update after `EventDataBatch` utility---**

use `EventDataBatch.TryAdd(EventData)` API to construct the batch. When the `EventData` cannot fit into the batch - this API will return `false`. Stop adding more events & then use the sender (`EventHubClient` or `PartitionSender`) to send the `EventDataBatch`.

following considerations motivated us to design `EventDataBatch` API:

- Help developers using our Client API - to deal with size of batch of `EventData`
- Abstract out region-wide/SKU-based `MaximumMessageSize` configuration: `EventHubs` service across the world could have different `Max EventData` sizes - across different `EventHub` regions and different `SKU`s of `EventHub`. We wanted to expose a uniform way for developers to construct `maximum message size` for any given environment. So, when `EventDataBatch` is initialized using `eventHubClient.createBatch()` API - the client negotiates `batchSize` with `EventHubs Service` and returns the `EventDataBatch` instance which can construct the correct size!

HTH!
Sree

Comment: I'd be happy with a higher level producer async producer that handles batching and other efficiency things for me like Kafka's, in the meantime I have my own code rebatching and will later build batches from the individual sends if I get that far.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/2.6.0 - the Nuget update...

Comment: Toss the link in the answer so it's more visible to future readers now that it's here, and I shall get around to accepting.

Comment: @Sreeram The SerializedSizeInBytes does not solve the problem for sending batches of messages. The batch size is greater than the sum of the individual EventData.SerializedSizeInBytes values. An IEnumerable<EventData> object where the sum is exactly 262144 bytes will throw a MessageSizeExceededException when calling EventHubClient.SendBatch. Do you know how I can account for the batching overhead data size?

Comment: Also noting that `SerializedSizeInBytes` is not available in the new .NET Core version of the SDK yet.

Comment: There is no SerializedSizeInBytes in Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs based EventData class. Any idea how to handle here ?

Comment: we introducted EventDataBatch utility to construct a batch with in the size.