# Why does EventHubClient.SendBatch() only support a single partition?

Tags: azure-eventhub

Apparently (based on an exception) [EventHubClient.SendBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatch.aspx) and [EventHubClient.SendBatchAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubclient.sendbatchasync.aspx) only support sending to a single partition per operation. This appears to be indicated indicated in the documentation by the method summary "Sends a batch of event data to the logical partition represented by PartitionId" which appears to be copied from the partition specific [EventHubSender.SendBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventhubsender.sendbatch.aspx).

Are there design considerations (vs just writing less code) in having the higher level client not rebatch as needed? 
The EventHubClient has control over the partition key hashing/distribution which is not available to callers of EventHubClient that wish to send a batch of data with differing keys that may lie on the same partition. Left to rebatch myself I need to make calls on the order of the number of messages as opposed to on the number of partitions which with small messages is easily two orders of magnitude difference.

Since it's [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263189/how-can-the-serialized-size-of-eventdata-be-determined-for-batching) necessary to rebatch it could be worse.

Answer (score 1):

I was assuming the PartitionKey on your EventData objects of the batch would be used to partition out.  But apparently not.
However, there's Paolo Salvatori, who wrote a nice set of Extension methods to provide good and easy support for sending in batches to Event Hub.
You'll probably like his post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2015/03/26/how-to-implement-a-partitioned-sendbatch-method-for-azure-service-bus-entities.aspx

Best regards

Comment: Yeah, that code looks similar to what I wrote (but didn't share) as a result of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263189/how-can-the-serialized-size-of-eventdata-be-determined-for-batching , though SerializedSize in bytes was added later. He is at least explicit that the batching only supports EventData with the same partition key.